# find By Id Could not work in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

return null using FindById

> Lead.java

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDelete;

import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDeleteAction;

import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener;
import org.springframework.lang.Nullable;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@Entity
@Table(name = "leads")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"createdAt", "updatedAt"},allowGetters = true)
public class Lead implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@NotBlank(message = "Name is mandatory")
private String name;

@Nullable
private String phone;

@Nullable
private String standard;

@Nullable
private String stream;

@Column(columnDefinition = "boolean default true")
private Boolean active = true;

@Nullable
private String remark;

@Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL default 'lead'")
private String type="lead";

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false )//, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
@JoinColumn(name = "school_id", nullable = false ) 
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })    
private School school;

@Nullable
@Column(name = "school_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Long schoolId;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "lead_status_id", nullable = false)
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
private LeadStatus leadStatus;

@Nullable
@Column(name = "lead_status_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Long leadStatusId;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
private User user;

@Nullable
@Column(name = "user_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Long userId;

@CreationTimestamp
private LocalDate createdAt;

@UpdateTimestamp
private LocalDate updatedAt;

public Lead() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public Lead(@NotBlank(message = "Name is mandatory") String name, String phone, String standard, String stream, String remark, String type, School school) {
    this.name = name;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.standard = standard;
    this.stream = stream;
    this.remark = remark;
    this.school = school;
}

public LeadStatus getLeadStatus() {
    return leadStatus;
}

public void setLeadStatus(LeadStatus leadStatus) {
    this.leadStatus = leadStatus;
}

public Long getLeadStatusId() {
    return leadStatusId;
}

public void setLeadStatusId(Long leadStatusId) {
    this.leadStatusId = leadStatusId;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

public String getStandard() {
    return standard;
}

public void setStandard(String standard) {
    this.standard = standard;
}

public String getStream() {
    return stream;
}

public void setStream(String stream) {
    this.stream = stream;
}

public Boolean getActive() {
    return active;
}

public void setActive(Boolean active) {
    this.active = active;
}

public String getRemark() {
    return remark;
}

public void setRemark(String remark) {
    this.remark = remark;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public School getSchool() {
    return school;
}

public void setSchool(School school) {
    this.school = school;
}

public Long getSchoolId() {
    return schoolId;
}

public void setSchoolId(Long schoolId) {
    this.schoolId = schoolId;
}

public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public Long getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(Long userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public LocalDate getCreatedAt() {
    return createdAt;
}

public void setCreatedAt(LocalDate createdAt) {
    this.createdAt = createdAt;
}

public LocalDate getUpdatedAt() {
    return updatedAt;
}

public void setUpdatedAt(LocalDate updatedAt) {
    this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
}

}
```

> Controller method

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
public HashMap<String, Object> getLeadById(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long leadId) {
    System.out.println(leadId);
    Lead lead = leadRepository.findById(leadId).orElseThrow(() -> new ItemNotFoundException("Lead", "id", leadId));
    return ResponseFormat.createFormat(lead, "Listed Successfully");
}
```

> LeadRepository.java

```
package com.lakshya.lakshya.repository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;


import com.lakshya.lakshya.model.Lead;

public interface LeadRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Lead, Long> {

}
```

Comment: Please post a question so the community can help you.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to extends `JpaRepository< , >`  ? maybe it will be the solution

```
public interface LeadRepository extends JpaRepository<Lead, Long> {

}
```

JpaRepository provides JPA related methods such as flushing the persistence context and delete records in a batch
because of this inheritance relationship, the JpaRepository contains the full API of CrudRepository and PagingAndSortingRepository.

Notify me if it works

Comment: just for make sure-
your sql server is working ? there is some leads in "leads" table?
when you make the system print of leadId you get the id?

Comment: I did not get it, why its not working. I used CrudRepository and technically it should work.

Comment: I tried JpaRepository but no luck.